# How to activate a new prop that a block introduces in a new release?

Tags: block-editor

I'm using [this plugin called Simple Code Block](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-code-block/) to display code snippets. In a recent release, it got a new toggle prop that displays a copy button on top of the code block but it must be turned on for every single code block in every single post.

Is there a simple way to enable it for all posts that contain this block? All I'm thinking that I can do is updating wp_posts table using the HTML generated by that toggle.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the plugin authors via [their official support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/simple-code-block/)?

Comment: Actually the situation is not specific to that plugin. It can be any other gutenberg block plugin that introduces a new feature that must be enabled in, for example, thousands of posts.